# How to sort array of objects by dates and make new arrays which will contain all objects with same date

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, sorting, reduce

I have a very specific problem in Javascript. I have array of objects, and each object contains some date.

```
const array = [
{name: 'first', date: '2020-05-06'},
{name: 'second', date: '2020-04-07'},
{name: 'third', date: '2020-05-06'},
{name: 'fourth', date: '2020-04-07'},
{name: 'fifth', date: '2020-04-09'}
]
```

For each unique date in array I need to make an object with key of that unique date and put all the elements of array in that object:

```
[{name: 'first', date: '2020-05-06'}, {name: 'third', date: '2020-05-06'}]
[{name: 'second', date: '2020-04-07'} {name: 'fourth', date: '2020-04-07'}]
[{name: 'fifth', date: '2020-04-09'}]
```

Any help would mean a lot. Thank you all!

Comment: Do you want an array of arrays or three separate variables?

Comment: Please share what you've tried till now. And, if none, please explore `.reduce()`. Please iterate over the array using `.reduce()` to generate an object and then you may transform the object into the set of 3 arrays you desire. Do you need those 3 arrays as part of a bigger array, though?

Comment: _"For each unique date in array I need to make an object with key of that unique date and put all the elements of array in that object"_ ... but what the OP shows as result looks closer to an array of arrays of date-specific items than to an object with date-specific entries.

Comment: @jabaa an array of array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use .reduce(), i leave you this example:

```js
let foo = [
{name: 'first', date: '2020-05-06'},
{name: 'second', date: '2020-04-07'},
{name: 'third', date: '2020-05-06'},
{name: 'fourth', date: '2020-04-07'},
{name: 'fifth', date: '2020-04-09'}
];
let boo = foo.reduce((acc, elem) => {
  (acc[elem.date] ??= []).push(elem);
  // since OP said they have eslint issues with ??=
  // following may be used instead of the above line
  // acc[elem.date] = (acc[elem.date] || []).concat([elem])
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log('output: ', boo);
```

result:

```js
{
  '2020-05-06': [
    { name: 'first', date: '2020-05-06' },
    { name: 'third', date: '2020-05-06' }
  ],
  '2020-04-07': [
    { name: 'second', date: '2020-04-07' },
    { name: 'fourth', date: '2020-04-07' }
  ],
  '2020-04-09': [ { name: 'fifth', date: '2020-04-09' } ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost any array specific task which somehow involves grouping will be solved most convenient by a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) based approach.

Regardless of the OP's final data structure one would start with the aggregation of an object which is going to feature `date` specific entries where each key represents a unique date value and each value is an array of items of such same dates.

In order to get an array of such grouped arrays one would pass the reduced object to [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

One of cause could always enforce a date specific item precedence by applying a [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) task first.

```js
function groupAndCollectSameDateItem(result, item) {
  // access item date.
  const { date } = item;
  
  // access or create `date` specific
  // group array and collect item.
  (result[date] ??= []).push(item);

  return result;
}

const dateItems = [
  { name: 'first', date: '2020-05-06' },
  { name: 'second', date: '2020-04-07' },
  { name: 'third', date: '2020-05-06' },
  { name: 'fourth', date: '2020-04-07' },
  { name: 'fifth', date: '2020-04-09' },
];

console.log(
  'index/map of arrays of same date items grouped by a date key ...',
  dateItems
    .reduce(groupAndCollectSameDateItem, {})
);
console.log(
  'sort items in ascending date order before creating the index ...',
  dateItems
    .sort((a, b) =>
      new Date(a.date).getTime() - new Date(b.date).getTime()
    )
    .reduce(groupAndCollectSameDateItem, {})
);
console.log(
  'array of arrays of same date items in ascending date order ...',
  Object
    .values(
      dateItems
        .sort((a, b) =>
          new Date(a.date).getTime() - new Date(b.date).getTime()
        )
        .reduce(groupAndCollectSameDateItem, {})
  )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***Edit***

> *"... Our project eslint does not allow the ??= symbol. –
> Marin"*

The alternative implementation for not using the [Logical nullish assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) might look similar to the next example code ...

```js
function groupAndCollectSameDateItem(result, item) {
  // access item date.
  const { date } = item;
  
  // access or create `date` specific
  // group array and collect item.
  let groupList = result[date];
  if (!groupList) {
    groupList = result[date] = [];
  }
  groupList.push(item)

  return result;
}

const dateItems = [
  { name: 'first', date: '2020-05-06' },
  { name: 'second', date: '2020-04-07' },
  { name: 'third', date: '2020-05-06' },
  { name: 'fourth', date: '2020-04-07' },
  { name: 'fifth', date: '2020-04-09' },
];

console.log(
  'index/map of arrays of same date items grouped by a date key ...',
  dateItems
    .reduce(groupAndCollectSameDateItem, {})
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank zou so much Peter, for this answer! As I'm copying this code snippet of yours in my projects, which is in vue, it gives me back an eror on this line: (result[date] ??= []).push(item); ---> can you find some other way to declare this line? Our project eslint does not allow the ??= symbol.

Comment: @Marin ... I provided a second code example with an alternative implementation.

Comment: Peter thank you so much! Your solution is more than valuable!

Comment: @Marin ... if everything was that helpful the OP might think about flagging the above answer as the accepted one.

Comment: @PeterSeliger, upvoted this comprehensive answer. Have found this from help-center: [**What to do when my question is answered?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), in case one needs to share info to other members in the community. OP/Marin - please have a read, as well.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is a groupBy implementation. Lodash library has it https://lodash.com/docs/#groupBy

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-twywom?file=index.js

Comment: Can you find solution please?

Comment: Use lodash library and call `groupBy(array, 'date')` it will return your output
See the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-twywom?file=index.js

Comment: Thnak you so much!